# Can DLNA Media Renderer also act as a controller as well?

Tags: media, upnp, dlna

I am little confused in this regard. I stream Youtube Video from my android phone (using a controller app called AllConnect) to my TV (renderer). During the playback, I can see the progress bar on the app being updated and I am able to seek in the time. Till here, I understand everything which is; My phone has discovered a DLNA renderer (TV) and is "pushing" the content to it.

Things start getting confusing, when I am also able to seek the content using my TV's remote, by pressing the back & forward buttons, which I guess seeks by +-10 secs.
How does this flow work ?? and the app is also aware of the seeks performed by the TV remote as the progress bar on the app moves accordingly.

Following are the specs on my TV:

1) RemoteControlReceiver.xml

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:sec="http://www.sec.co.kr/dlna" xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">
<specVersion>
<major>1</major>
<minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>
<device>
<deviceType>urn:samsung.com:device:RemoteControlReceiver:1</deviceType>
<friendlyName>[TV]UA32D5000</friendlyName>
<manufacturer>Samsung Electronics</manufacturer>
<manufacturerURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</manufacturerURL>
<modelDescription>Samsung TV RCR</modelDescription>
<modelName>UA32D5000</modelName>
<modelNumber>1.0</modelNumber>
<modelURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</modelURL>
<serialNumber>20090804RCR</serialNumber>
<UDN>uuid:9aaf1aa7-b2c9-f9d5-6b21-2df55015c03a</UDN>
<sec:deviceID>BDCISIPC2MN3M</sec:deviceID>
<serviceList>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:samsung.com:service:TestRCRService:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:samsung.com:serviceId:TestRCRService</serviceId>
<controlURL>/RCR/control/TestRCRService</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/RCR/event/TestRCRService</eventSubURL>
<SCPDURL>TestRCRService.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
</serviceList>
</device>
</root>
```

2) PersonalMessageReceiver.xml

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:sec="http://www.sec.co.kr/dlna">
<specVersion>
<major>1</major>
<minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>
<device>
<deviceType>urn:samsung.com:device:PersonalMessageReceiver:1</deviceType>
<friendlyName>[TV]UA32D5000</friendlyName>
<manufacturer>Samsung Electronics</manufacturer>
<manufacturerURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</manufacturerURL>
<modelDescription>Samsung TV PMR</modelDescription>
<modelName>UA32D5000</modelName>
<modelNumber>1.0</modelNumber>
<modelURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</modelURL>
<serialNumber>20081224PMR</serialNumber>
<UDN>uuid:fc866c7a-5ace-8368-600f-711705796dd8</UDN>
<sec:deviceID>BDCISIPC2MN3M</sec:deviceID>
<iconList>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
<width>48</width>
<height>48</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/pmr/icon_SML.jpg</url>
</icon>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
<width>120</width>
<height>120</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/pmr/icon_LRG.jpg</url>
</icon>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
<width>48</width>
<height>48</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/pmr/icon_SML.png</url>
</icon>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
<width>120</width>
<height>120</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/pmr/icon_LRG.png</url>
</icon>
</iconList>
<serviceList>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:samsung.com:service:MessageBoxService:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:samsung.com:serviceId:MessageBoxService</serviceId>
<controlURL>/PMR/control/MessageBoxService</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/PMR/event/MessageBoxService</eventSubURL>
<SCPDURL>MessageBoxService.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
</serviceList>
</device>
</root>
```

3) SamsungMRDesc.xml

```
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0" xmlns:pnpx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pnpx/2005/11" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2008/09/devicefoundation" xmlns:sec="http://www.sec.co.kr/dlna">
<specVersion>
<major>1</major>
<minor>0</minor>
</specVersion>
<device>
<deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:1</deviceType>
<pnpx:X_compatibleId>MS_DigitalMediaDeviceClass_DMR_V001</pnpx:X_compatibleId>
<df:X_deviceCategory>Display.TV.LCD Multimedia.DMR</df:X_deviceCategory>
<dlna:X_DLNADOC xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0">DMR-1.50</dlna:X_DLNADOC>
<friendlyName>[TV]UA32D5000</friendlyName>
<manufacturer>Samsung Electronics</manufacturer>
<manufacturerURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</manufacturerURL>
<modelDescription>Samsung TV DMR</modelDescription>
<modelName>UA32D5000</modelName>
<modelNumber>AllShare1.0</modelNumber>
<modelURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</modelURL>
<serialNumber>20081224DMR</serialNumber>
<UDN>uuid:6f4e620e-f056-581b-752b-1c0ce33bc370</UDN>
<sec:deviceID>BDCISIPC2MN3M</sec:deviceID>
<iconList>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
<width>48</width>
<height>48</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/dmr/icon_SML.jpg</url>
</icon>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/jpeg</mimetype>
<width>120</width>
<height>120</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/dmr/icon_LRG.jpg</url>
</icon>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
<width>48</width>
<height>48</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/dmr/icon_SML.png</url>
</icon>
<icon>
<mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
<width>120</width>
<height>120</height>
<depth>24</depth>
<url>/dmr/icon_LRG.png</url>
</icon>
</iconList>
<serviceList>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl</serviceId>
<controlURL>/upnp/control/RenderingControl1</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/upnp/event/RenderingControl1</eventSubURL>
<SCPDURL>RenderingControl1.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ConnectionManager</serviceId>
<controlURL>/upnp/control/ConnectionManager1</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/upnp/event/ConnectionManager1</eventSubURL>
<SCPDURL>ConnectionManager1.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
<service>
<serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1</serviceType>
<serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:AVTransport</serviceId>
<controlURL>/upnp/control/AVTransport1</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/upnp/event/AVTransport1</eventSubURL>
<SCPDURL>AVTransport1.xml</SCPDURL>
</service>
</serviceList>
</device>
</root>
```

Comment: Your phone is not "pushing": it's just telling the TV the location of a media file and informing it that you want to play/pause/FF this file. The TV then decides to start streaming or pausing as it likes. It can also do those things based on other input, like the remote control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, in DLNA 1.0, only `DMP(Digital Media Player)` and `DMS` is introduced. `DMP` acts as both player and controller, so the pattern is well known as `2-box-pull`. In DLNA 1.5, `DMC(Digital Media Controller)` is separated and now `DMC` control `DMR(Digital Media Renderer)` rendering, and this pattern is known as `3-box-push`

It's OK that `DMR` controls current media (may be a song, or a playlist) like `stop`, `seek` and so on, but after any changes, `DMR` would send `notification` to `DMC` and `DMC` update the playing state then.

In more detail, after pressing `seek` buttons, TV change state from `PLAYING` to `TRANSITIONING`, and when `seek` finishes, change back to `PLAYING`. Meanwhile, when `DMC` got `notification` from TV, it will do `AVTransport::GetPositionInfo` to sync position with TV.